# How to send xml tag as parameter in ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

### I'm having a problem with sending XML tag as a parameter in Ajax request

At first I've tried to send it as string but the request fail because the ajax encoding the tags to **"&-lt;Id&-gt;16385&-lt;/Id&-gt;",**
so I've convert it to xmlDoc using jquery also the request fail.
here's sample of my code, also you'll find the request payload below.

```
let id='<Id>16385</Id>';

  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( id );
  $xml = $( xmlDoc );
  id = $xml.find( "Id" )[0];
  let obj={
    method: "ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit",
    namespace:
      "http://schemas/comassetegOrganizationChart/MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit/operations",
    param :{
      "MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id":id,
       MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name:"Test"
    } 
  }
  cordys.cordysAjax(obj.method,obj.namespace,obj.param).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  });

function cordysAjax(method,namespace,par) {
    return $.cordys.ajax({
      method: method,
      namespace:namespace,
      parameters: par,
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "xml"
    });
}


**when sending the parameter as string**

 <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><SOAP:Body><ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit xmlns='http://schemas/comassetegOrganizationChart/MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit/operations' ><MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id>&'lt;Id&gt;16385&'lt;/Id&'gt;</MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id><MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name>Test</MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name></ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>

 **When sending the parameter as XML**

    <SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><SOAP:Body><ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit xmlns='http://schemas/comassetegOrganizationChart/MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit/operations' ><MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id/><MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name>Test</MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name></ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit></SOAP:Body></SOAP:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is i don't have to send the value of the first parameter as xml tag like '16385'
the correct answer is

```
 param :{
      "MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id":{Id:16385},
       MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name:"Test"
    }
```

Ajax will format the request payload like this

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<SOAP:Body>
    <ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit xmlns='http://schemas/comassetegOrganizationChart/MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit/operations' >
        <MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id>
            <Id>16385</Id>
        </MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id>
    </ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit>
</SOAP:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML provides CDATA section to contain strings that might contain reserved characters

```
<![CDATA[<Id>16385</Id>]]>
```

Your XML could be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP:Body>
    <ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit xmlns="http://schemas/comassetegOrganizationChart/MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit/operations">
      <MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id><![CDATA[<Id>16385</Id>]]></MOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit-id>
      <MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name>Test</MOD_SYS_OC_entity_Name>
    </ReadMOD_SYS_OC_entity_unit>
  </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```